# Formula to find lines in column that contain text from other column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns in Excel, A and B.
I need to find all lines (that is, put them in another column) in B that contain the entirety of any cell in column A. For example, suppose A contains:

```
apple
banana
```

And B contains:

```
I like apples
I like pears
I like bananas
```

Then I would to see, in column C, the following lines:

```
I like apples
I like bananas
```

I'd like a way to do this using only Excel formulas. Thanks in advance!

Note: If A contains something like "pea" and B contains "spearmint", then the phrase "I like spearmint" would appear in column C - the above is only an example

Comment: Also, I chose to keep my question general for the sake of others who might use this question and its answers, but I can add specifics that would make it easier to answer if need be.

Comment: No, we assume that isn't possible. I'll edit my question to specify that

Comment: You might be able to do that with Excel formulas only but I suspect they will be complicated and hard to support and maintain. I suggest you look into VBA and RegEx. That route would solve it for you.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll look around for a way to do this with (my rather limited knowledge of) Python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments about the complexity of the needed formula are correct, as it needs some intermediate computations of 2D arrays. But here it is FWIW...

Enter the following formula in `C1`, press 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> then copy/paste to fill down column `C` (take a look at the example diagram for more details):

```
C1:
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$99)/
  (ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE("*"& $A$1:$A$4 & "*"), $B$1:$B$99))),ROW(1:1))), "")
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Excellent - I had some notion that it would be difficult but I did not imagine it would be this complicated. It works well for me but I'm trying to understand the logic behind it - for the "A$A4" part, is that because the length of the A column in this example is 4?

Comment: @Koloktos that's correct; the formula wont work if the range of keywords (column A) includes empty cells. On the other hand the limit `99` on column B is only to reduce the computation time. What the formula does is, it computes a "matrix" of matches between keywords in A and sentences in B, then it indexes the rows of matched entries in the matrix (that's the aim of `Row(1:1)` which will increase at each row to find the next match).